# Convert a Dict Comprehension into a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Could someone explain why these two results are different?

I was trying to convert a multi key dictionary comprehension into a DataFrame.

First approach:

```
Dict1={(i,j):i+j for i in range(2) for j in range(2)}
print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Dict1, orient="index").reset_index())
```

Result: Data Frame has one index (it should have two)

```
    index  0
0  (0, 0)  0
1  (0, 1)  1
2  (1, 0)  1
3  (1, 1)  2
```

Second approach:

```
Dict2={(i,j):{"value":i+j} for i in range(2) for j in range(2)}
print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Dict2, orient="index").reset_index())
```

Result: Data Frame has two index

```
       level0  level_1  value
0        0        0      0
1        0        1      1
2        1        0      1
3        1        1      2
```

I managed to do it using the second approach, but why the first approach does not work? why it did not retain the dictionary keys as two different index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try either

```
pd.DataFrame(list(Dict1.values()), index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(Dict1.keys()))
```

or

```
Dict1={(i,j):[i+j] for i in range(2) for j in range(2)}

pd.DataFrame(Dict1).T
```

It appears that it will not default a dict keys that are tuples to multiindex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your first suggestion did work, but I got an error on your second suggestion "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index". Nevertheless, the question is ¿do you know why adding the '{}' and a name ("value") changed the behavior of the DataFrame.from_dict function?

Comment: Made a small edit to clarify the second line. I'm not sure why your second approach coerced the multiindex. Hopefully someone else can clarify.